# plt.show()を行ってもプロットできない

Tags: python, matplotlib

VS CodeでPython3.6.5を走らせています。スクリプトで`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`としていますが、`plt.show()`を行ってもプロットのウインドーは出るのですが、何も描画されずウインドーは全面真っ白のままです。エラーメッセージは出ません。

`plt.show()`の前には各種の処理をしてその結果を例えば`plt.plot(x, y, label="result")`などのコードを入れてあります。以前IDLEで走らせた時には出ていました。今はHomebrew、Pyenvで構築しVS Codeを入れています。

#### 追記

次のような簡単なコードでもプロットが出てきません。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 折れ線グラフを出力
left = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
height = np.array([100, 300, 200, 500, 400])
plt.plot(left, height)
```

そしてVSCodeの下にあるターミナルウインドーには、

```
/Users/user1/Desktop ; env "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" /Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/bin/python /Users/user1/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.10.1/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd_launcher.py --client --host localhost --port 50736 /Users/user1/Desktop/test.py iMac:Desktop user1$
```

と出ています。

何が原因かご教示お願いいたします。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらのご質問ですが、`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` と `plt.show()` 以外にコードはありますか？　無い場合は何も出ないのが正常動作であり、ある場合はそのコードの情報も無いと何とも言えないです。質問文下の「編集」から追記して頂ければと思います。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: はい、plt.show() の前には各種の処理をしてその結果を例えばplt.plot(x, y, label="result")などのコードを入れてあります。以前IDLEでは知らせた時には出ていました。今はHomebrew、Pyenvで構築しVS Codeを入れています。

Comment: Shimak さん、情報ありがとうございます！　ただ、これだけだと私の手元で再現するための情報が足りないです。ヘルプページの[確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)を参考に、第三者でも問題を再現できるように操作手順を教えて頂けませんでしょうか？ (質問文に直接追記して頂ければと思います。)　たとえば matplotlib の[チュートリアル](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html)にあるような簡単なソースコードでもグラフは表示されないのでしょうか。また、VS Code 上で Python を実行するときはどのような操作をなさいましたか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。はい次のような簡単なコードでもプロットが出てきません。　

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# 折れ線グラフを出力
left = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
height = np.array([100, 300, 200, 500, 400])
plt.plot(left, height)

そしてVSCodeの下にあるターミナルウインドーには、
/Users/user1/Desktop ; env "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" /Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/bin/python /Users/user1/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.10.1/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd_launcher.py --client --host localhost --port 50736 /Users/user1/Desktop/test.py
iMac:Desktop user1$
と出ています。

Answer (score 1):

IDLEで走らせると表示されるが、Pyenv+VSCodeの環境では簡単なコードでもプロットが出力されないということであれば、コードの問題ではなく使用している環境の問題だと推測されます。

PyenvもVSCodeも便利なツールなのですが、ブラックボックスになっている部分があるので、思い通りに動作しない場合には調べるのに手間がかかります。今回の場合、IDLEで走らせる場合と条件が違ってくるものには次のようなものがあります。

- 中間にデバッガー ptvsd_launcher.py が入っている影響
- VSCodeの設定ファイル`launch.json`, `sttings.json`の影響
- PyenvでインストールしたPythonは、公式からダウンロードしたPythonとは全く同じではない影響
- matplotlibの設定ファイルが環境が違うと変わる影響
- PyenvをインストールするとPATHの先頭に`$HOME/.pyenv/bin`を追加するのでその影響

この問題を解決するには、最初に、これらの条件を変えてどこに問題があるかを見つける必要があります。IDLEで走らせると表示されるということなので、IDLEの代わりにVSCodeで走らせてみてプロットが出力されるかどうかから始めてみるといいと思います。

Comment: ５点の問題候補ご教示頂きありがとうございました。matplotlibrcはbackend をTkAggにしました。VS Codeで走らせるとエラーなくPlotウインドーは開いてくれるのですが、ウインドーの中は真っ白で何も描画されません。できましたらlaunch.json, sttings.jsonの設定例を教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: sys.pathを見ましたところ、次のようになりました。問題箇所がどこでどう修正すべきでしょうか？
'/Users/user1', 
'/Users/user1/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.10.1/pythonFiles/experimental', 
'/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python36.zip', 
'/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6', 
'/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
'/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
'/Users/user1/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions'
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ターミナルウインドーに内容から、VSCodeでF5で起動していると思いますが、自分のMacの環境だと VSCodeはデフォルトの設定でmatplotlibは正常に描画されます。sys.pathの方も問題はないと思います。

Comment: launch.jsonは長い内容になっていてこのコメント欄には文字数超過でかけません。Python3.6.5が走りmatplotlibが正常に走るためのlaunch.jsonの例を教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: launch.jsonを削除しても描画されています。設定をすべて消してみたらどうですか。

Comment: VS Code以外でも同じ問題があり、色々試した結果matplotlibrcのbackendのTkAggの代わりにQtAggにし、PyQt5をインストールしたらPlotの中身が表示されました。今の所副作用はまだ無いのでこれで進められると思います。様々なアドバイスありがとうございました。